# Adding parent scope to anonymous function - JavaScript to Angular 2

Tags: javascript, function, angular, scope

I am attempting to include an old JavaScript module within an Angular 2 project and I've hit a problem with accessing parent scope.

```
let testString = "Parent Scope Accessed!";

Object.keys(data).forEach((function(Key, Index) {
    if(filter.type == 'parameter') {
      Object.keys(dirArray).forEach(function(dirKey, dirIndex) {
        linkArray = dirArray[dirKey];
        if(filter.dir == 2) {  //Direction filter
          Object.keys(linkArray).forEach(function(linkKey, linkIndex) {
            if(filter.type != 'sub')) {
              dataObject = linkArray[linkKey];

              //ERROR with scoping occurs below.  Need to add parent scope.
              console.log(this.testString);
            }
          });
        }
      });
    }
}));
```

I've tried to do something like this:

```
let testString = "Parent Scope Accessed!";

Object.keys(data).forEach((function(Key, Index) => {
    if(filter.type == 'parameter') {
      Object.keys(dirArray).forEach(function(dirKey, dirIndex) => {
        linkArray = dirArray[dirKey];
        if(filter.dir == 2) {  //Direction filter
          Object.keys(linkArray).forEach(function(linkKey, linkIndex) => {
            if(filter.type != 'sub')) {
              dataObject = linkArray[linkKey];

              //ERROR with scoping occurs below.  Need to add parent scope.
              console.log(this.testString);
            }
          });
        }
      });
    }
}));
```

But that gives an entirely new set of issues, but at least the IDE indicates that the parent scope has been added.  I assume I am not using the '=>' syntax correctly.  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: How about just `Object.keys(data).forEach((Key, Index) => {...});`?

Comment: Thanks Harry - I needed to drop the function keyword.  Missed functions class 101 it seems.

Comment: To be fair it's not 101 though ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the `function` word and just use the fat arrow, `=>`, when defining a function

```
 let testString = "Parent Scope Accessed!";

Object.keys(data).forEach(((Key, Index)=> {
    if(filter.type == 'parameter') {
      Object.keys(dirArray).forEach((dirKey, dirIndex)=> {
        linkArray = dirArray[dirKey];
        if(filter.dir == 2) {  //Direction filter
          Object.keys(linkArray).forEach((linkKey, linkIndex)=> {
            if(filter.type != 'sub')) {
              dataObject = linkArray[linkKey];

              //ERROR with scoping occurs below.  Need to add parent scope.
              console.log(this.testString);
            }
          });
        }
      });
    }
}));
```

**OR**

Define the root `this` in a variable (`var that` in this case):

```
var that = this;
let testString = "Parent Scope Accessed!";

Object.keys(data).forEach((function(Key, Index) => {
    if(filter.type == 'parameter') {
      Object.keys(dirArray).forEach(function(dirKey, dirIndex) => {
        linkArray = dirArray[dirKey];
        if(filter.dir == 2) {  //Direction filter
          Object.keys(linkArray).forEach(function(linkKey, linkIndex) => {
            if(filter.type != 'sub')) {
              dataObject = linkArray[linkKey];

              //ERROR with scoping occurs below.  Need to add parent scope.
              console.log(that.testString); //Use that instead of this here to refer to the parent scope
            }
          });
        }
      });
    }
}));
```

Comment: This worked perfectly.  I knew I was not using the '=>' syntax correctly.  Thank you.